# MySQL - Want to incrementally DELETE anything older than x amount of rows

Tags: mysql, max, limit, sql-delete

I've a bloated table without a timestamp field. So the best way I've come up with to clean this table up is to keep the most recent 7,000,000 rows (works out at about 1 year worth of data).

What I've been trying is to use the MAX(primary_id) - 7000000 and delete anything older than this in increments of 500 (LIMIT).

```
DELETE
FROM tblBloat
WHERE (Select MAX(primaryID) - 7000000 from tblBloat) > primaryID
ORDER BY primaryID desc
LIMIT 500
```

This however returns an error "You can't specify target table 'tblBloat' for update in FROM clause.

Also tried this, however mySQL doesn't seem to like the JOIN on a DELETE statement:

```
DELETE 
FROM tblBloat
INNER JOIN (select MAX(primaryID) - 7000000 as 'max'
FROM tblBloat) ab
WHERE primaryID < ab.max
ORDER BY primaryID DESC
LIMIT 500
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the highest ID that needs to be deleted with:

```
set @max_delete_id = (
  select primaryID
  from tblBloat
  order by primaryID desc
  limit 1
  offset 7000000
);
```

Then delete all rows with equal or smaller IDs:

```
delete
from tblBloat
where primaryID <= @max_delete_id
limit 500;
```

Then repeat the second query until no rows are affected.

I would though use a higher LIMIT (maybe 10000) or skip the LIMIT.

A common workaround for your query would be to wrap your subquery into a *derived table* (subquery in FROM clause):

```
DELETE
FROM tblBloat
WHERE (SELECT * FROM (Select MAX(primaryID) - 7000000 from tblBloat)x) > primaryID
ORDER BY primaryID desc
LIMIT 500
```

But note that `primaryID` might have gaps for several reasons, and you would keep less than 7M rows.

Comment: Setting the variable and deleting using this worked a treat. Thanks very much